# SQLite Compare Date Not working

Tags: javascript, angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have a table 'Calls' contains a column 'CallDate'
CallDate is of Type TEXT and contain values like `"2017-12-09T04:55:06+02:00"`

I am trying this query but always getting empty. It is weird, it is written in the documentation that date takes this format (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
this.SQLObj.executeSql("SELECT * from Calls WHERE date(Calls.CallDate) = date(?1)", '2017-11-30').then(res => {
                        console.log(res);
                    })
```

and I am sure I have Calls with that Date.

Comment: I tried your query on a mock database and it worked as expected. We will need additional information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think the issue was I should surround the parameter with []. Like this :
['2017-11-30']